# How to pipe a text files contents into another python program's command line argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

My issue is finding a way to feed content like so from a text file called wordlist.txt:

```
line1..
line2..
line3..
```

into a python program's command line argument and loop through each string to run the command with each line/string of the wordlist.

The python program works like so:

```
 python program.py -t wordlist.txt arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I'm trying to code a script that will run the program piping or feeding the second command line argument each line from the wordlsit.txt file.

For instance I want this to be the result:

```
python program.py -t line1 -p arg2 -U arg3 -P arg3 
python program.py -t line2 -p arg2 -U arg3 -P arg3 
python program.py -t line3 -p arg2 -U arg3 -P arg3
```

(Ignore -t this is just a parameter that stands for target)

I've tried:

```
import sys
import requests
import os
import exec_cmd
def run():
    files = "wordlist.txt"
    exc = "python program.py -t $files -p arg2 -U arg3 -P arg4"
    while True:
            exec(exc)
run()
```

I've also tried:

```
import subprocess

t = "wordlist.txt"
t = open(t, "r")

for i in t:
    subprocess.run(["python", "program.py", "-t", i, "-p", "args1", "-U", "args2", "-P", "args3"])
```

Comment: Barring the question of why you're doing this (is program.py something you cannot edit or import and can only call? That sounds... weird), you can either read the file using python and then feed in the information within in your exc str, or use shell/bash to open and pipe the output in. Also, use subprocess.run rather than exec.

Comment: @Melvin I'm trying to run a program that is similar to a brute force script that tries each value inside of the informationlist file inside of another python program for instance: python program.py -t 10.0.0.1 -P args ..... I'm trying to try different addresses from the informationlist file 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 etc

Comment: For instance say I have a exploit that needs a target IP as the -t parameter. Instead of inserting each IP address to test I want to code a python script that runs a wordlist of targets inside of the python exploit program. python program.py -t targets.txt ....etc

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to do is something along the lines of:                       wordlist = raw_input("enter the name of the target file list: ")
wordlist = open(wordlist, "r")

run = "python exec_cmd.py -t %s" % wordlist
exec(run)

Comment: What program.py does itself is fine, but instead of calling exec, can you edit program.py such that it has one callable function, with args as what you plan to feed in currently via argv, and then import program and call that function? exec calls aren't really recommended (dynamic execution so your ide can't flag errors in advance, difficult to read/debug exc, etc), so I would avoid it as much as possible.